# How can I remove duplicate record in php (Array unique)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an array of records and I want to remove the duplicate record. I know we can use array_unique() to remove duplicate value but in my case I have an array of records like(Date, Url, xyz). I want to skip the date column while checking the duplicate record.

You can check my code bellow.

```
$array = array(
    array('2014', 'http://example.com', 'xyz'),
    array('2013', 'http://example.com', 'xyz'),
    array('2010', 'http://example.com', 'xyz'),
    array('2011', 'http://example.com', 'xyz'),
    array('2019', 'http://example.com', 'xyz')
);
```

You can check that i have 5 same records just the date is different so I just need one record like

```
array('2019', 'http://example.com', 'xyz')
```

I hpoe you can understand. If you have anyother question please comment bellow
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works for me please try this code.

```
$array = array(
    array('2014', 'http://example.com', 'xyz'),
    array('2013', 'http://example.com', 'xyz'),
    array('2010', 'http://example.com', 'xyz'),
    array('2011', 'http://example.com', 'xyz'),
    array('2019', 'http://example.com', 'xyz')
);

$arr = array();

foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
    $id = $item[0];
    unset($item[0]);
   $arr[$id] = $item;
}

$input = krsort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC);


echo '<pre>';
print_r(array_unique($arr));
```

Hope this will help you.